# PhoneGap plugin "startApp" not working with jQueryMobile

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, plugins

I have included the startApp PhoneGap plugin in one of my app. There is a

tag with id "myTest". I was trying to open the "Twitter" app with the startApp plugin.
Here is the code that I am using:

```
function onDeviceReady() {

    $("#myTest").on("click", function() {
        alert("clicked");
        navigator.startApp.check("twitter://", function(message) { 
            alert("Success");
        },
        function(error) {
            alert("ERR");
        });
    });
}
```

I am using jQueryMobile for this. When the app is lunched for the first time or re-started again after killing it, the startApp works file but when I navigate to different pages within the application and come back and click the link to open the Twitter, this does not work.

Is it the issue with jQueryMobile only or something else? Any help please?

The PhoneGap plugin I am using is this one: [startApp](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/2397)

Comment: Should you be using 'navigator.startApp.start' instead of (or as well as) 'navigator.startApp.check'  ?